# Vue Resource config root does not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

Actually I wan't to set up the default url so I am not typing the same url again and again. Here is my main.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://localhost:8085'



new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Then in my component I Write methods like this :

```
 getData: function () {
                alert('masuk sini');
                this.$http.get('/api/datageneration/environment')
                    .then((response) => {
                        return response.json();
                    }).then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.lists = data.content;
                });
            }
```

I run it on port 8082 using command `npm run dev` but why when I call the methods, it always aim to port 8082? I already set up the root for port 8085 where my back end running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [configuration documentation](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/config.md) for vue-resource states:

> Note that for the root option to work, the path of the request must be relative. This will use this the root option: `Vue.http.get('someUrl')` while this will not: `Vue.http.get('/someUrl')`.

So, try to remove the leading `/` in your call to the api:

```
this.$http.get('api/datageneration/environment')
```